# How does CONTEXT's auto-generation of code documentation work?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, documentation, modules

Unlike LaTeX's core, CONTEXT core macros have quite readable code and, specially in the lack of up-to-date documentation for certain commands, one can learn a lot by just reading the code itself and the documentation provided therein.  That's also a good source of learning how to write CONTEXT macros.

In fact, there is a way to generate documentation right from the code itself, which adds the provided annotations to the PDF output along with the actual code.  According to [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules), this is done via the following command line.

`context --ctx=s-mod core-con.mkiv`

This generates a `core-con.mkiv.prep` file and also compiles it into a nice PDF output.

How does the same functionality work for Lua files?  The same page on Garden suggests the following.

`context --ctx=x-ldx core-con.lua`

This generates a `core-con.lua.prep` and then a `core-con.lua.prep.prep` file but not the desired supposedly HTML documentation.  **Question**:  What am I doing wrong here?

**Question**: What tags beside the `\module` definition at the top and the index mechanism `\macros` can we use inside the `%D` comments (in MkIV sources)?  (I know we can use any TeX code; I'm asking what special macros are available.)  I also notice a special `%C` tag for the copyright statement but don't know what effect it has.  Are there any other special comment codes?

**Question**: What about the tags in the Lua file?  Those are more mysterious and scarcer.  Why are these HTML tags, anyway, instead of TeX macros?

Answer (score 3):

It should be fixed in beta, see
[CONTEXT distribution - beta version](http://www.pragma-ade.com/download-2.htm)

Comment: I just updated my CONTEXT to the latest beta (2016.05.08 17:30) but the Lua documentation code still does not work.  This time it complains that `\scitepacked` is not defined.  I couldn't find it anywhere outside `x-ldx.mkiv`.  It seems to be a misspelling of `\stoppacked`.

Comment: what about removing the old .prep file and replacing  \scitepacked by \stoppacked  ?

Comment: Thanks!  I actually patched `x-ldx.mkiv` and it worked.

Comment: Could you address the other parts of the question as well?